# python read the data from binary file and writing it to signed int

Tags: python, file, binary

im currently trying to get the bytes from python string and save it to signed int array
i try to get all the bytes from the file than split the '\x00' in an array then try to get the int from that byte but i keep getting the following error
'TypeError: cannot convert unicode object to bytes'

```
file=open('norm.raw','rb')
data=file.read()
file.close()
#data=binascii.b2a_hex(data)
byteArr=str(data)[2:-1]

for byte in byteArr:
    i+=1
    if byte == "\\":
        cadena.append(byteArr[j:j+i])
        j=j+i
        i=0
for stri in cadena:
    print(int.from_bytes('\\'+stri[:-1],byteorder='big',signed='true'))
```

dont know if this is the best way to get the signed int bytes from a file in python, if some one knows a better way to do it please help me.

edit:
currently i can take the byte notation of a byte in the array
i can extract the b'x02' but now i cant add the  character \ at the beginning to convert it to signed int.

Comment: Could you add some data of your input ?

Comment: last bytes from file:\xff\xf0\xff\xf0\xff\xf1\xff\xf0\xff\xf3\xff   , it should be: -1,-16,-1,-16,-1,-15,-1,-16,-1,-13,-1

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question. I've rolled back your edit, it can be found in the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `decode` function that works on a bytes object.

```
bs = b'\x31'
x = int(bs.decode())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

EDIT:

The previous version takes the unicode value to decode. If you have value stored in the raw byte. Then you can get integers in the following way.

```
binary_bytes = b'\xff\xf0\xff\xf0\xff\xf1\xff\xf0\xff\xf3\xff'

for i in range(len(binary_bytes)-1):
       print(int.from_bytes(binary_bytes[i:i+1], byteorder='big', signed='true'), end=', ')
```

Output : `-1, -16, -1, -16, -1, -15, -1, -16, -1, -13, -1`

Comment: i get this error when i try it: 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x11'

Comment: You have to decode the bytes and then send it to the function `int`. Do not pass the `b'\x11'` directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to your comment.

I suppose you have a range of bytes like this `b'\xff\xf0\xff\xf0\xff\xf1\xff\xf0\xff\xf3\xff'`

So, you can do somthing like this in order to have your desired output:

```
def func(a):

    data = [a[k:k+1] for k in range(len(a))]
    final = []
    for k in data:
        final.append(int.from_bytes(k, byteorder = 'big', signed = True))

    return final

a = b'\xff\xf0\xff\xf0\xff\xf1\xff\xf0\xff\xf3\xff'

print(func(a))
```

Output:

```
[-1, -16, -1, -16, -1, -15, -1, -16, -1, -13, -1]
```